# Iterating values in an array

Tags: c#, arrays

If I have an integer array of variable length [n] is it possible to iterate it so that each value increments only when the next value has reached n-1.

for example if n=3:

```
int[] intArray = {0, 0, 0};
```

increment intArray[] such that:

```
intArray = {0, 0, 1}
intArray = {0, 0, 2}
intArray = {0, 1, 0}
intArray = {0, 1, 1}
intArray = {0, 1, 2}
intArray = {0, 2, 0}
intArray = {0, 2, 1}
intArray = {0, 2, 2}
intArray = {1, 0, 0}
intArray = {1, 0, 1}
...
intArray = {2, 2, 2}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps to think of patterns in your problems - sometimes they suggest general solutions that may be simple to break down and implement.

In this case, the array contents are acting like base-n numbers (base-3 in the specific example). So you could consider an algorithm for incrementing an arbitrary numeric base, and once you have that move on to coding it.

A function that would "increment" a base-n number would start by incrementing the least-significant digit and checking it for overflow. In base-10, we would retain the 0, and carry the 1 to the next most significant digit. In an arbitrary numeric base, this is the same as resetting the digit to zero and incrementing the next most significant digit.

There are special cases to consider. What if you're asked to increment the "maxint" in your numeric base, e.g. `{2, 2, 2}`? Will you add another significant digit? Will you peg the value at "maxint", or wrap to `0`? Will you throw an exception? There's no "right" answer, unless you already have a specification.

In pseudo-code, here's the idea:

```
increment( digits  , base ) {
 for (place=digits.length - 1; place >= 0; place-- ) {
   digit = digits[place]++;  // increment digit in this place
   if (digit < base)
    break;
   else
    digit = 0; // overflowed, so "wrap" to zero, increment next place
 }
 return digits;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly with a little fiddling, module is [here](http://pastebin.com/eb9Z0brT) if anyone needs it.